# Find invalid HTML in markdown files

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, kramdown

I used some crazy alien-tech* to convert my HTML content to markdown for Jekyll.

I noticed that some files have invalid HTML. There are a gazillion files so no human can manually review all of them quickly.

Is there a way I can quickly list all files with invalid HTML ignoring the markdown content? Possibly using a Windows app?

*app

Answer (score 1):

You should try [HTML Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php), clean it using [tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) before parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html), for example, seems to pass through invalid html contained in the markdown input. Pass the HTML output from Pandoc to [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)  for validation. Something like:

```
$ pandoc input.md | tidy
```